# How to read a csv in Python using Pandas' read_csv after a certain line having specific sting?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a few files where I want to start importing csv after a line having a certain text. Number of row is not fixed, but the text in that row is.

E.g. One file may have 50 lines then the line having "Data Starts Here" followed by csv. And another may have 120 line then the line "Data Starts Here". So cannot use row_number arg.

Comment: Read it in as a string, split it, parse it into sections. Pass those sections to `read_csv` with `io.StringIO`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. You need to iterate through the (copy of the) file, find out the right value of skiprows, then use that.

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import copy

fake_file = """






data starts here
col1,col2,col3,col4
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
9,10,11,12"""


def read_csv_after_line(file,str_to_find):
    iter_file = copy.copy(file)
    for i,line in enumerate(iter_file):
        if str_to_find.lower() in line.lower():
            print(i,line)
            return pd.read_csv(file,skiprows=i+1)

read_csv_after_line(StringIO(fake_file),'data starts here')
```